# Foliations in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, characteristic-p, foliations

Ekedahl wrote about foliations in positive characteristic, over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as a subsheaf of the tangent sheaf, that are closed with respect to involution and $p$-power.

**My question is:** does there exist a reference about this theory but over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Do you really mean the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$ or maybe the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ which is a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ? If you do mean the first, what are some of your motivations? By the way, I think foliation theory can be defined over any field of positive characteristic as well.

Comment: Look at this paper:
Miyaoka, Yoichi(J-TOKYM)
Deformations of a morphism along a foliation and applications. Algebraic geometry, Bowdoin, 1985 (Brunswick, Maine, 1985), 245–268, 
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 46, Part 1, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1987. 

Comment: Ekedahl himself asks about it in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306432 at page 7. I would say it is a good, and a weird question.